# Where to load scripts or css from CDN, head or body?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, cdn

Where should I put the code for CDN scripts or styles? In the head element or before the closing body tag?

Comment: Why do you think it is any different for CDNs?

Comment: Because CDNs are faster?

Answer (score 2):

Put the css files in the head, your javascript at the bottom of the body.

This way the content will load faster, also if you put the scripts t the top it could be that your page rendering will stop at some point because you're downloading the javascript files.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531314/should-i-write-script-in-the-body-or-the-head-of-the-html) or [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Why so? Any references?

Comment: But, your reference says that you should put scripts in the head unless you have load issues :(

Answer (score 1):

There are different philosophies regarding the best location for the script tag.

Here is another philosophy: [Adding a script to HTML](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html)

> Putting scripts in HEAD is easy and guarantees that they will be available before the page is shown.

There is also (in above document):

> Scripts at the end of BODY
>
> A script can also be at the bottom of page body. In this case it
> executes after the page is shown.
>
> Good, because user doesn’t have to wait for scripts.
>
> Bad, because the functions become available after the HTML is loaded. A user has a chance to click on button which may not work. Usually adding special code that hides functionality until the script
> has loaded resolves the problem.

AFA style, it works best in head

Good luck
;)