# how to enable button by javascript in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I'm trying to enable a button in JavaScript as long as the user enter a text . 
What is wrong with this code?is it because of the using fieldset?

```js
function setText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  if (x != "") {
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = 'false';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="file1">
    <legend><img src="fb-login.png" height="70" width="70" /> :</legend>

    Email: <input id="mail" type="email" onchange="setText()"><br> password: <input type="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="ok" disabled> <br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: remove the quotes from 'false'; I vote to close this as a Typo.

Comment: Lots of stuff. Which is an answer about as clear as your question.

Comment: You should write the script tag just before body tag ends not in head section

Comment: @SarojSasmal that is not at all necessary.

Comment: Yeah, i know but it's a good practice ..

Comment: @SarojSasmal Says who? Such a tiny script lives well in the head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531314/should-i-write-script-in-the-body-or-the-head-of-the-html

Comment: You are correct, Thanks

Comment: @dan  I created a snippet for you. The script in the snippet STILL lives inside `<script></script>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct approach rather than using onchange you should use oninput / onkeyup:

```js
 function setText(){
  var x=document.getElementById("mail").value.trim();
  if(x !=""){
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
      }
  else{
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
      }
    }
```

```html
 <form>
  <fieldset id="file1">
    <legend><img src="fb-login.png" height="70" width="70"/> :</legend>

       Email: <input id="mail" type="email" onkeyup="setText()"><br>
      password: <input type="password"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" id="btn" value="ok"  disabled> <br>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

**UPDATE**

A shorter approach is given by @mplungjan below:

```
function setText() {
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = document.getElementById("mail").value.trim()=="";
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn").disabled = document.getElementById("mail").value.trim()==""`

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the update.. updated my answer..

Comment: but why the if and else?

Comment: @mplungjan else for disabling the button if the user removes the text.

Comment: My code does either. Try it.

Comment: @mplungjan yes actually it does.. but I haven't given that approach in my answer and therefore voted up your comment.

Comment: No problem. I rolled it back. I just find it a waste of code

Answer (score 1):

First, use `oninput` event instead of `onchange` to bind typing events. Then, `false` is a boolean keyword in JavaScript, not a string. Here is a working example:

```js
function setText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mail").value.trim();
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = x == "";
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="file1">
    <legend><img src="fb-login.png" height="70" width="70" /> :</legend>

    Email:
    <input id="mail" type="email" oninput="setText()">
    <br> password:
    <input type="password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="ok" disabled>
    <br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn").disabled = document.getElementById("mail").value.trim()=="";`

Comment: @mplungjan apart from the `trim()` part I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: It replaces all of your `var x = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    if (x != "") {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    }`

Comment: Oh sorry you're right it wasn't clear with the line break in your comment (the line is too long). Thanks, I will edit my answer :)

Comment: oninput is the better event handler

Comment: ok,i will try this. but where should i put the function? and the script in your code is used for?

Comment: The function is replacing yours. Leave it where it was.

Comment: but my function is inside the script. in your code the script is written seperatly

Comment: Just let it inside the <script></script> tags, replace your function with this one.