# Why does <script> appear in <body> when I defined it outside of <body>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm busy pumping out some web projects from the Odin Project. Anyway, I'd like to adhere to the software engineering process of taking small steps and testing them. Now, for instance, I'd like to see the output of document.querySelector("body"). It is my understanding that I should place the  tag somewhere, I'm not too sure what the best place is. The [StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531314/should-i-write-script-in-the-body-or-the-head-of-the-html) on this topic are quite ambiguous. Here's my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createDOM.js"></script>  
</html>
```

createDOM.js:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
console.log(body);
```

Console:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="createDOM.js"></script>
</body>
```

Me:

```
$ ????????
```

Comment: This is a old school way for adding external JavaScript to a html page, why dont use it on head with `defer` attribute, like this `<script src="myscript.js" defer>`

Comment: Placing any element outside of `body` or `head` is invalid HTML, and browsers are automatically fixing the worst errors in the source code. See [`<html>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html). "_Permitted content: One `<head>` element, followed by one `<body>` element._"

Comment: Awesome! I've put the script references in the <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way webengine play with source. Most ( and almost all ) webengine put everything into body that can be ( i.e following the standard ) because body is taken as subroot for DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp your script inside the body tag, at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="createDOM.js"</script>
</body>

</html>
```